# Process AJAX request with multiple types of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I tried to find information in google, but no results there. I want send to server array with keys ('data':'unknown','datakey':'status') and file.

I tried this one, but settings *contentType:false* *and* *processData:false* removing keys:

```
$('#null').on('click', function(efile) {
var inFile = new FormData();
inFile.append('outFile', efile.target.files[0]);
});

$.ajax({
    cache:false,
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    url:'fileservice.php',
    data:{'data':'unknown','datakey':'status', inFile}, 
    type:"POST",
    success: function(eresponse) {
        alert(eresponse);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"contentType" is type of data you sending such as 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

Default is: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Try below code
    $.ajax({

```
    url:'fileservice.php',
    cache:false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data : JSON.stringify({'data':'unknown','datakey':'status', inFile}),
    processData:false,
    type:"POST",
    success: function(eresponse) {
        alert(eresponse);
    }
});
```

Let me know if still not solved you problem.